# Instantiating a generic type

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to convert an existing class to use generics, and am getting stumped while converting the constructors.

The original class was a POJO that contained logic for moving from one room to another in a text-based console game. Literally, it was a class that held some string triggers that would fire the action (eg. the user types "walk right"), a description, and a pointer to the new Location.

The current, non generic version of the class looks like this:

```
public class Navigation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String trigger;
    private String description;
    private Location target;

    public Navigation() {
        this("", "", new Location());
    }

    public Navigation(String trigger, String description, Location target) {
        this.trigger = trigger;
        this.description = description;
        this.target = target;
    }

    // plus getters, setters, etc.
}
```

(The `Location` class is another POJO that describes a location. It is irrelevant.)

I want to extend the `Navigation` class to be able to handle targets that are not `Location`s. I thought that the best way to do this would be to convert the `Navigation` class to use generics, so I tried this:

```
public class Navigation<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    private String trigger;
    private String description;
    private T target;

    public Navigation() {
        this("", "", new T());
    }

    public Navigation(String trigger, String description, T target) {
        this.trigger = trigger;
        this.description = description;
        this.target = target;
    }

    // plus getters, setters, etc.
}
```

However, this doesn't compile at the line `this("", "", new T());` because `T` cannot be instantiated. Is is possible to instantiate the generic type object in this context?

Comment: Please look to the right at all those related questions.

Comment: I did. They're passing in a Class and the answer is to call `clazz.newInstance()`. This is the default constructor. I don't *have* a class.

Comment: Then pass the `target` instance directly. Those are your only options.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Due to type erasure, you can't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically have two choices:

1.Require an instance:

```
public Navigation(T t) {
    this("", "", t);
}
```

2.Require a class instance:

```
public Navigation(Class<T> c) {
    this("", "", c.newInstance());
}
```

You could use a factory pattern, but ultimately you'll face this same issue, but just push it elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 2):

No, and the fact that you want to seems like a bad idea. Do you **really** need a default constructor like this?

Comment: Due to the way the object is initially created by parsing XML and YAML data, I need to have a default constructor. `target` is also not allowed to be null, which is why I'm trying to instantiate a default version of it here.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas What if `T` didn't have a no-arg constructor?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'd expect the same behavior that would happen if I called `clazz.newInstance()` on it, then: an InstantiationException.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas That would happen at runtime. Generic `T` is a compile time concept.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do `new T()` due to type [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The default constructor can only be

```
public Navigation() {
    this("", "", null);
}
```

​
You can create other constructors to provide default values for trigger and description. You need an concrete object of `T`.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer, please? What does `new T()` erase to? `new Object()`?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It doesn't erase to anything. It's syntactically incorrect.